# cosmosDb SQL API LINQ optimization when comparing two list of strings

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a where LINQ which has to compare two list of strings and find if there is any matching string present in both the list, how can I achieve this while keeping the return type still IQueryable(to actually avoid firing query)

For Example,

```
 var keys = ["12","23"];
 var query = await repo.WhereAsync(obj => obj.SomeList.Intersect(keys) != null);
 var list = (await query.Take(pageLimit * pageNumber).ToListAsync()).Skip(pageLimit * (pageNumber - 1))
```

And as per my knowledge currently Intersect is not supported by cosmosDb LINQ wrapper